# How to create oracle sequence with param "cache" sets to "No cache" using sqlalchemy orm

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

Python 3.7, Sqlalchemy 1.3.6, Oracle 12c.

How to create sequence in Oracle using Sqlalchemy ORM with parameter CACHE sets to "NO CACHE".

For example, there is a table class, prepared by me (arg ??? can be integer):

```
class Tests(BazaModel):
    _ _tablename_ _ = 'testtbl'
    testtbl_id = Column(Integer, Sequence('testseq', cache=???), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(51))
```

I have found information that since sqlalchemy `ver. 1.1.12` there is possible to invoke constructor with arg cache, see example below:

```
__init__(name, start=None, increment=None, minvalue=None, maxvalue=None, nominvalue=None, nomaxvalue=None, cycle=None, schema=None, cache=None, order=None, optional=False, quote=None, metadata=None, quote_schema=None, for_update=False).
- cache
```

optional integer value; number of future values in the sequence which are calculated in advance. Renders the CACHE keyword understood by Oracle and PostgreSQL."

But arg "cache" takes values: None, integer greater than 1 and none of them of course not produces what I want.

At this moment I don't want to invoke explicitly raw sql over database to change sequence settings in similar way like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "xxx_APP"."testseq"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCACHE  NOORDER  NOCYCLE;
```

I want to do this using Sqlalchemy ORM.
Is there any chance to do this?

Comment: This is probably not the answer you wanted to hear, but: are you sure you want to do this?  I have literally never seen a good reason to disable sequence caching.  If you're looking for a gapless sequence, Oracle sequences will never do that.  (Because numbers will still be lost because of errors, rollbacks, restarts, etc..)  It might help to explain exactly why you want to use `NOCACHE`.

Comment: Thank you Jon. I agree with you. This question is only the kind of questions "if it is possible in sqlalchemy orm" after I talked with colleagues and made a few tests.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone is still stuck on this (as I just was), here's a fairly easy solution that works for me. This approach tweaks the generated SQL, by interpreting cache values of 0 or 1 to use the NOCACHE option. I agree with the comments about whether it is usually necessary, but I just found it annoying that something that was added daily was incrementing by 20 each day! And the technique works well for other customisations of SQL in Oracle.

```
# Change this for your own connection
user, pwd, host, service = "USER", "PWD", "HOST", "SERVICE"

# START OF SPECIAL CODE >>>
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateSequence
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles

@compiles(CreateSequence, "oracle")
def visit_create_sequence(element, compiler, **kw):
    """ 
    Modify create sequence for Oracle to support NOCACHE, by 
    translating a cached number of 0 or 1 into NOCACHE 
    """
    nocache = element.element.cache in {0, 1}
    if nocache:
        element.element.cache = None
    sql = compiler.visit_create_sequence(element, **kw)
    if nocache:
        sql += " NOCACHE"
    return sql
# <<< END OF SPECIAL CODE

# Now on with creating the sequence
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Sequence
conn_str = f"oracle+cx_oracle://{user}:{pwd}@{host}:1521/?service_name={service}"
engine = create_engine(conn_str)
metadata = MetaData(engine)
test_seq = Sequence('test_seq', metadata=metadata, cache=1)
metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

The resulting sequence looks like this:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('SEQUENCE', 'TEST_SEQ') from dual;
CREATE SEQUENCE  "USER"."TEST_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCACHE  NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  GLOBAL
```